# C# SQLite vs DataTable: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a problem with getting value from a DataTable row.

This is the query :

```
SELECT COALESCE((FE1), 0) + COALESCE((FE2), 0) + COALESCE((FEE), 0) 
FROM DRC 
WHERE DTS = '2021-04-21T09:57:47+02:00'
```

In DB Browser, it returns the following value: `-5700`  (as expected)

With different timestamp it may also result values in 2 decimals, therefore I decided to cast it to decimal while I retrieve it from DataTable.

But the below code throws an error

> Specified cast is not valid.

```
...
string dts = "2021-04-21T09:57:47+02:00"
decimal sum = 0; 

query=$"SELECT COALESCE((FE1),0)+ COALESCE((FE2),0) +  COALESCE((FEE),0) FROM DRC WHERE DTS =  '{dts}'";
 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     sum = row.Field<decimal>(0); // Exception: System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
}
...
```

With eg. integer, double etc type it results the same.

Comment: Debug and check the datatype returned in the `DataTable`. Also I have never see this way of reading from a `DataTable`. You should maybe try the standard way by using `sum += Convert.ToDecimal(row[0]);`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `Field` method - it simply provides a convenient way to access the column values - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are performing a **raw** read, so the returned values in the `DataTable` will be typed as the underlying ORM chooses to represent them - in this case probably a `SQLiteDecimal` struct or similar.

I don't understand why you're even using a `DataTable` though, since you're reading a single row of a single resultset. Just consume the `SQLiteDataReader` directly:

```
using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
{
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            sum = reader.GetDecimal(0);
        }
    }
}
```